# How to force 2 C# methods always appear together in compile time?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

I have two C# methods RegisterTasks() and WaitForAll(), and whenever RegisterTasks() is called, WaitForAll() must be called in the same code block too. Just wondering if there's a way to tell C# compiler to make sure WaitForAll() always appear together with RegisterTasks(), and give a compiling error otherwise?
Thanks~

Comment: In a word, no. You'll have to follow the workarounds suggested by Igor or Jason. This is not an issue the compiler can help you with, it's one of *design* and making your API easy to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reduce the visibility of `RegisterTasks()` and `WaitForAll()`, and expose a method that calls them both.

Comment: I believe the idea is that they must be called near each other, but not consecutively.

Comment: Then the new method should take a delegate to called in-between.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, and sorry for my late response:)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer, as everyone else has said, is no.

I assume these methods are separate because the caller may wish to execute other code in between them.  You may wish to consider creating a single combined method that takes a delegate as a parameter and then invokes that delegate when desired.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to properly document the contract and trust the end user to use the methods correctly.

Answer (score 0):

No but you can do some designs. Example:

```
public void RegisterTasks(){
  // do something
  WaitForAll();
}
```

Or

```
public void RegisterTasks(){
  // do something
  privateWaitForAll();
}
public void WaitForAll(){
  // do something
  privateWaitForAll();
}
private void privateWaitForAll(){
  // do something
}
```